# How to combine values in a single array separated by space (like matrix) and combined by square brackets []

Tags: python, arrays, line-plot

I am working with "Masked arrays"  and found a way to add the values in each of the arrays together by `zip()` and `append()`.

```
time_coord= zip(MY,Sl_time)
   
for MY_i, Sl_time_i in time_coord:
        time_.append(MY_i + Sl_time_i)
```

the output is stored in another array but when printing the output it looks like this:

```
[39.098]

[20.859]

[25.078]
...
```

Whereas I want it to be together so I can end up using this array as my x values for a line plot like this:

```
[39.098  20.859  25.078...]
```

Thank you so much

Comment: your question is quite unclear, especially the variables you are using. If you could specify the data types of all the variables used it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I am using nc data and the variables at hand are MY(mars years) which is of type "numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray" and Sl_time is a list. (I can not edit MY it is given in the data but I can change Sl_time if needed)

Comment: what data type is time_ ? try `time_.extend(MY_i + Sl_time_i)`.

Comment: time_ is an empty list. I am attempting to add MY values to Sl_time values and store them in an array which is time_. I tried your suggestion and I get error TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to loop on an array and apply arithmetic operation on all the values in that array?

Comment: Example: 'Sl' is a "numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray" which has dimension 2. I want to find the average between the values and store them in a big array I used : Sl_time= [(np.mean(Sl))/360]. When finding the type of it I get a float which I want to be in a big array as such [23 24 25 26 ....] , and NOT numbers separated one by one

Comment: Can you send me the whole code. So I can try to fix it on my end. (yes it's possible to apply arithmetic operations to the whole list).

Comment: Hi, hope ur still here. this is the code.. for filename in glob.glob("*.nc"):
    n = Dataset(filename)
    lons=n.variables['lon'][:]
    #print (lons)
    lats=n.variables['lat'][:]
    #print (lats)
    dust_tau=n.variables['dust_tau'][:,:]
    #print (dust_tau)
    waterice_tau=n.variables['waterice_tau'][:,:]
    #print (waterice_tau)
    waterice_flag=n.variables['waterice_flag'][:,:]
    #print (waterice_flag)
    Sl = n.variables['Ls'][:]
    #print (Sl)
    MY = n.variables['MY'][:]
    #print (MY)

Comment: time_ = []
    result = []
     
    
    
    #Put Sl values in one array

    for i in range(len(Sl)):
        Sl_time= (np.mean(Sl))/360
        #print(Sl_time)
        result.append(Sl_time)
    print(result)                                                                                                        #adding lists for time coordinate
    time_coord= zip(MY,Sl_time)    ERROR IN THIS LINE FROM Sl_time :('numpy.float64' object is not iterable)
   (rest of code)
    for MY_i, Sl_time_i in time_coord:
      time_.append(MY_i + Sl_time_i)
    
    #print(time_)

Comment: trying to plot time_ vs watericetau_mean (time series). Thank you in advance!!! <3